# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT 'Invalid use of Group function' error that DOESN'T involve an aggregate function

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, group-concat

I have a MySQL stored procedure (shown below) that's supposed to build a list of IDs from a table of hierarchically related records. I'm having to re-engineer an older stored procedure to switch from using a simple CONCAT function to GROUP_CONCAT because the former couldn't handle the sizes of the lists being generated (i.e., the lists are going well over the 1024 character limit of the CONCAT function).

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE SPTest (top_id INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE ids_all TEXT;
    SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
    SET ids_all = top_id;
    SET @str = GROUP_CONCAT('SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR \', \') ',
        'FROM tbl WHERE nha_id = ', top_id, ' INTO @ids_tmp' SEPARATOR '');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @str;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    WHILE @ids_tmp != "" DO
        SET ids_all = GROUP_CONCAT(ids_all, @ids_tmp SEPARATOR ', ');
        SET @str = GROUP_CONCAT('SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR \', \') ',
            'FROM tbl WHERE nha_id IN (', @ids_tmp, ') INTO @ids_tmp' SEPARATOR '');
        PREPARE stmt FROM @str;
        EXECUTE stmt;
    END WHILE;
    SELECT ids_all AS ids;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

The problem is this routine is generating the following error when I try to call it (and sometimes it returns this error when I try to create the Stored Procedure):

```
ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function
```

When I manually create the same kinds of queries this code would build and run them at the command-line, they work perfectly fine -- no errors of any kind, and I get the results I expect. I've seen posts (both here on Stack Exchange and elsewhere) which say that MySQL doesn't support nested aggregate functions, but the concatenation here is just being done to strings. So I thought that maybe somehow it was seeing the `GROUP_CONCAT` in the string and burping because of that, so I tried putting "XXXX" in place of "GROUP_CONCAT" in the string and then using the `REPLACE` function to switch it back, but that made no difference. I also tried it with `WHERE` and `HAVING` for the criteria clause, but neither one worked. I've also done an extensive web search and was unable to find anything that was in any way helpful.

I don't know what else to try, mainly because I can't see what's wrong with the syntax here. Any help would be appreciated.

### Update 1:

I have since tried a modified version of the script where the `GROUP_CONCAT` merges data from a subquery like this:

```
SET @qrystr = GROUP_CONCAT('SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(c SEPARATOR ", ") ',
    'FROM (SELECT id AS c FROM tbl WHERE nha_id IN (', @ids_tmp, 
    ') AS d INTO @ids_tmp' SEPARATOR '');
```

but that made no difference either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Bill Karwin's answer regarding the need to use `SELECT` with `GROUP_CONCAT`, I was able to see how my code needed to be changed. Rather than using a `SET` statement to assign the values to the variables, I need to use a `SELECT ... INTO ...` construct, as shown here:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE ASSEMBLY_LIST_TEST (top_id INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE ids_all TEXT DEFAULT '';
    SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
    SET ids_all = top_id;

    # Find the 1st-level children of 'top_id' to start building the list
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ", ") FROM tbl ',
        'WHERE nha_id = ', top_id, ' INTO @ids_tmp' SEPARATOR '') INTO @qrystr;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @qrystr;
    EXECUTE stmt;

    # Recursively find the children of each level of children of the previous loop & add to the list
    WHILE @ids_tmp != '' DO
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ids_all, ', ', @ids_tmp SEPARATOR '') INTO ids_all;
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ", ") FROM tbl ',
            'WHERE nha_id IN (', @ids_tmp, ') INTO @ids_tmp' SEPARATOR '') INTO @qrystr;
        PREPARE stmt FROM @qrystr;
        EXECUTE stmt;
    END WHILE;
    SELECT ids_all AS ids;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

This now produces exactly the result I was looking for. Of course, the recursive query approach is a much better solution for what I want this to do, but maybe my solution will help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `GROUP_CONCAT()` as a scalar function; it must be used in the context of a set of rows. Similarly, you can't use any other aggregate function without a table reference:

```
SET @x = MAX(<expr>); -- makes no sense
```

Ideally you should upgrade to MySQL 8.0 if you haven't already, and use a [recursive CTE query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) instead:

```
WITH RECURSIVE hierarchy AS (
  SELECT top_id AS id
  UNION
  SELECT tbl.id FROM tbl JOIN hierarchy ON tbl.nha_id = hierarchy.id
)
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ', ') AS ids_all FROM hierarchy;
```

That would eliminate the need for using loops or prepare/execute or temp variables.

Comment: Actually you CAN join string literals. When I said "When I manually create the same kinds of queries this code would build and run them at the command-line, they work perfectly fine", that's exactly what I did -- I typed-in "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR \', \') ', 'FROM tbl WHERE nha_id IN (', @ids_tmp, ')' SEPARATOR '');" and got the exact result I was looking for. That being said, I didn't know about RECURSIVE CTE queries, and I do have MySQL 8.0. That may very well solve my problem, but it'll have to wait until tomorrow morning for me to try that out!

Comment: Yes, you can pass string literals to GROUP_CONCAT() but you can't use it as a bare expression without being part of a SELECT statement.

Comment: THAT's where the problem is. Thanks for pointing that out. Please see my answer and revised code. And thanks for the information about recursive CTE queries; that works great.